# Weird JS function "sliced" execution flow

Tags: javascript, canvas, pixel

I have a really weird behaviour with the execution of a function.

Here is the context: I'm writing a kind of drawing tool which I based on canvas manipulations. I need to take the data from the main canvas and apply a process on it every N seconds (replacing a color with another, and set to 0,0,0,0 every other pixel). The processed data are then put in the saveCanvas.

The function:

```js
function replaceColorByAnotherColor(data, oldRgbColor, newRgbColor, opacity) {
    let i = 0;
    let testTime = new Date();
    let testPos = 0;
    let testNeg = 0;
    while (i < data.length) {
        if (
            data[i] >= oldRgbColor.r - 50 &&
            data[i] <= oldRgbColor.r + 50 &&
            data[i + 1] >= oldRgbColor.g - 50 &&
            data[i + 1] <= oldRgbColor.g + 50 &&
            data[i + 2] >= oldRgbColor.b - 50 &&
            data[i + 2] <= oldRgbColor.b + 50
        ) {
            testPos++;
            data[i] = newRgbColor.r;
            data[i + 1] = newRgbColor.g;
            data[i + 2] = newRgbColor.b;
            data[i + 3] = opacity;
        } else {
            testNeg++;
            data[i] = 0;
            data[i + 1] = 0;
            data[i + 2] = 0;
            data[i + 3] = 0;
        }
        i += 4;
    }
    console.log(data.length);
    console.log(testPos);
    console.log(testNeg);
    console.log(new Date() - testTime + ' ms');
}
```

Here is a [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/TheMadOcarina/k978agvf/68/) that tries to reproduce the situation.

So here is the issue I'm facing: sometimes, my process function takes a very long time to execute (from ~80ms to more than 7 seconds!).

When I use the "performance" tool in Chrome debugger, here is what I found:

When after the execution I don't refresh the object by reading the picture from the main canvas  (which I have to do for my whole code to work correctly), my function execution is normal, like [this JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/TheMadOcarina/k978agvf/67/) :
[image: normal execution]

But if after the execution, I refresh the object with `getImageData()` on the main canvas, the execution of my function is kinda slice (and is way longer) which I never saw before, like in [this JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/TheMadOcarina/k978agvf/67/):
[image: sliced execution]
Zoomed:
[image: sliced execution zoom]

I also pointed out that in either cases, the 3 or 4 first executions works like a charm, before the bug (or whatever it is) happens.

I don't have a clue on what is going on with this execution.

Do you have any idea, or do you ever faced this kind of behaviour before?

Thanks!

**EDIT 1:**

I managed to have the same behaviour without the React stack in [this JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/TheMadOcarina/tmrqofg5/5/). By the way, sorry for the hideous base64 string at the begining of the fiddle. It's my first time with JsFiddle, I don't know how to include other files and I think my issue is linked with the size of the image.

As @Bonatti suggested, I included the main function above.
And here is the main code:

```html
<div>
  <canvas style="width:200px" id="mainCanvas" width="3280" height="2464"></canvas>
  <canvas style="width:200px" id="saveCanvas" width="3280" height="2464"></canvas>
</div>
```

```js
var test = {
    src:"data:image/png;base64,iVBOR....."
}

let imageData = null;
let mainTimeout = setTimeout(() => {processCanvas()},10000);

let mainCanvas = document.getElementById('mainCanvas');
let mainCtx = mainCanvas.getContext('2d');

let saveCanvas = document.getElementById('saveCanvas');
let saveCtx = saveCanvas.getContext('2d');

let image = new Image();
image.onload = () => {
    mainCtx.drawImage(image,0,0);
    imageData = mainCtx.getImageData(0,0,3280,2464);
}
image.src = test.src;

var refreshImageData = () => {
    imageData = mainCtx.getImageData(0,0,3280,2464);
}

var processCanvas = () => {
    console.log('====== PROCESS ======');
    clearTimeout(mainTimeout);
    refreshImageData();
    replaceColorByAnotherColor(imageData.data, {r:255,g:0,b:0}, { r: 0, g: 255, b: 0 }, 255);
    saveCtx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
    refreshImageData();
    mainTimeout = setTimeout(() => {processCanvas()},10000);
}
```

The execution result:

```
====== PROCESS ======
32327680
161417
7920503
63 ms
====== PROCESS ======
32327680
161417
7920503
225 ms
====== PROCESS ======
32327680
161417
7920503
2566 ms
```

And after that, it never goes below 2000 ms.

**EDIT 2:**

It looks like the issue happens whenever I read or write in the `data` array.

It happens if I do:

```js
while (i < data.length) {
    if (data[i] === oldRgbColor.r) {
        testPos++;
    } else {
        testNeg++;
    }
    i += 4;
}
```

But not if I do

```js
while (i < data.length) {
    if (i % 5) {
        testPos++;
    } else {
        testNeg++;
    }
    i += 4;
}
```

Comment: The question is clear, and well worded, but I highly advise you putting the scripts inside your question, as well the [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: That's a good advice, thanks! I included the main code, and I managed to reproduce the behaviour without the React stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I just found the issue: it was the inner `oldRgbColor` and `newRgbColor` components access.

I just put `.r` `.g` and `.g` in separates variables and do

```js
while (i < data.length) {
    if (
        data[i] >= oldR - 50 &&
        data[i] <= oldR + 50 &&
        data[i + 1] >= oldG - 50 &&
        data[i + 1] <= oldG + 50 &&
        data[i + 2] >= oldB - 50 &&
        data[i + 2] <= oldB + 50
    ) {
        test1++;
        data[i] = newR;
        data[i + 1] = newG;
        data[i + 2] = newB;
        data[i + 3] = opacity;
    } else {
        test2++;
        data[i] = 0;
        data[i + 1] = 0;
        data[i + 2] = 0;
        data[i + 3] = 0;
    }
    i += 4;
}
```

and now it works like a charm!

I can't explain why, I don't understand why it behaved like that.

I mark my answer as resolved, but if anyone bump into this and understant what happened, feel free to explain it!